# chartjs - show hide specific dataset with click on element outside graph

Tags: dataset, chart.js, show-hide

The chartjs feature to show/hide a dataset by clicking on the legend is really nice. Is it possible to achieve the same but clicking on for instance a checkbox outside the chart canvas?

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick

```
chart.data.datasets.forEach(function(e) {
    e.hidden = true;
});
```